# How Can I Measure the Complete Running Time of an Async Function in NodeJS Profiling?

Tags: node.js, performance, profiling

I'm currently working on optimizing an API, which is fundamentally an asynchronous function in NodeJS. I initially attempted to use Chrome DevTools for profiling, but the timing results it provides are based on the time taken to execute the script, and not on the time spent waiting for IO operations.

My goal, however, is to figure out which parts of the function are consuming the most time. To achieve this, I need a way to measure the total running time of the function, including the waiting time for IO. Is there a way to do this using Chrome DevTools? Or maybe there's another approach that I could use? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not being able to remember the name of a tool I saw someone using for this earlier. But I found a couple options suitable for NodeJS -

You can use `ClinicJS`:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/clinic

It includes three tools: Clinic Flame, Clinic Bubbleprof, and Clinic Doctor. Clinic Flame helps you visualize CPU flame graphs, Clinic Bubbleprof analyzes event-loop activity, and Clinic Doctor diagnoses issues and provides recommendations based on collected data.

`Chrome DevTools` is also an option:

You can start your Node.js application with the `--inspect` flag to enable debugging and profiling, and then use the Chrome browser to connect to the Node.js instance for profiling. The Performance and Memory panels in DevTools offer insights into CPU usage, memory allocation, and event timings.

This is not an exhaustive list, there can be many other tools as well.